# Tic Tac Toe with swing - different colors for X and O

Tags: java, swing

I want to customize the colors for the different players; "X" and "O".
The code where I initialize the board is under here, and I don't understand why it's not working. When running the program, the X's and O's are both blue, even when I added the if/else if loops.

```
private void initializeBoard() {
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 100));
    if(currentPlayer.equals("X")) {
      button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if (currentPlayer.equals("O")) {
      button.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
    board[i][j] = button;
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("") &&       
        hasWon == false) {
          button.setText(currentPlayer);
          hasWon();
          choosePlayer();
        }
      }
    });
    pane.add(button);
  }
}
```

}

You can check the whole code at my GitHub if language doesn't bother you (I translated some stuff to English here, though in my code I have used Norwegian): https://github.com/ibrarnaseer/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/master

Comment: That if block needs to be within the ActionListener. You've got it where the buttons are created, and at that time, current player will be "X" and only "X". That creational code and the if block will not be magically re-called when the button is pressed, not unless you (again) put it within the action listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is where you are setting the foreground color. You need to set it inside the `ActionListener` because is where you know what is the player who chooses that position. Something like this:

```
private void initializeBoard() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         JButton button = new JButton();
         button.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 100));
         board[i][j] = button;
         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("") &&       
                  hasWon == false) {
                  button.setText(currentPlayer);
                  if(currentPlayer.equals("X")) {
                     button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  } else if (currentPlayer.equals("O")) {
                     button.setForeground(Color.RED);
                  }
                  hasWon();
                  choosePlayer();
               }
            }
         });
         pane.add(button);
      }
   }
}
```